# Difference between "where is he from" and "where he is from"

Tags: wh-questions

what will be the question of he is from the USA? Is it "where he is from?"/"where is he from?". And why is it so?

Comment: You would need to give us rather more context. does it involve a question? please supply a full sentence. you may find our sister site EL & L more useful for this type of question.

Comment: Hello, 3661798. This doesn't look like the sort of question ELU is intended for; basic grammar needs to be learnt at school or via courses, or from websites intended to provide such help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Oh, go ahead and tell them the answer. It's not useful to keep it a secret, after all, and many folks here wouldn't be able to answer it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the statement

- *He is from the USA.*

into a *Yes/No* question, one

1. moves the first auxiliary verb (***is*** in this example; all forms of *be* are auxiliaries)
   to a position **before** the subject noun phrase (***he*** in this example), and
2. adds a question intonation if speaking, or a question mark if writing.

So the result is

- *Is he from the USA?*

That's an actual question; if you say it, you're requesting the addressee to give you information.

However, *Yes/No* questions can also be signalled just by the intonation in a simple sentence.
This is mostly done in speech, so *He is* sounds wrong, since pronouns are usually contracted.
You could just say

- *He's from the USA?*
  (**with** the question intonation -- it can't be left out)

and folks will generally interpret it as a *Yes/No* question.

If you want to make a *Wh*-question, **first** you make a *Yes/No* question,
**then** you select the appropriate *Wh*-word for the word you're questioning,
and then you put that *Wh*-word at the beginning of the question, and delete the part it questions.

- *He is from the USA.*
- I*s he from **the USA***? (*Y/N* question; ***the USA*** is what you're questioning)
- ***Where*** is he from? (***where*** is the appropriate *Wh*-word for *the USA*, which is deleted)